# Использование вертикальной табы(\v), жадных(Greedy) и супержадных выражений

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Что такое вертикальная таба `\v`?
Чем супержадный метод отличается от жадного?
Аналогично для нежадного.

Не надо меня отсылать к гуглу (или lmgfy). Если хочется послать, пошлите лучше на "natribu" или на конкретный сайт с описанием проблемы для трехлетних кодеров.
Ибо в наиболее популярных ресурсах я прочел, но ничего не понял. Особенно с табой.

Comment: "...для идиотов" забыл добавить. =/

Comment: действительно, относительно \v интересно было бы узнать.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Пример входных данных:

```
<tag attr='val'>123 123</tag>
```

Цель: найти совпадение между угловыми скобками (неважно, какими, суть в том, чтобы посмотреть на разницу в поведении).

Используем нежадный (ленивый, lazy) квантификатор: `<tag.*?>`
В этом случае движок регулярных выражений будет в буквальном смысле стараться "отделаться побыстрее". Как будет происходить поиск:

1. нашли `<tag`. Идем дальше, подбираем под `.*`
2. след. символ пробел. Подходит под `.*` - отлично, хватит с меня, идем дальше подбираем под `>`
3. символ `a` - черт, придется возвращаться назад, опять подбираем под `.*`, но уже начиная с `a`
4. `a` подходит под `.*` - и хватит, подбираем под `>`
5. символ `t` - черт... -

и так далее, с постоянным откатами назад. 
Результат: `<tag attr='val'>`

Используем жадный (greedy) квантификатор: `<tag.*>`
Движок будет пытаться подобрать побольше символов под каждый квантификатор и производить откаты только если совпадение не найдено:

1. нашли `<tag`. Идем дальше, подбираем под `.*`
2. след. символ пробел. Подходит под `.*` - отлично, но пробуем идти дальше и пытаемся и следующие символы проматчить с `.*`: `attr='val'>123 123</tag>` - все, нечего больше добавить, идем дальше
3. подбираем под `>` - а текста-то уже нету. Придется откатываться назад - переходим на символ назад и подбираем `>`
4. след. символ `>` - подходит под `>`. Текст закончился, паттерн закончился

Результат: `<tag attr='val'>123 123</tag>`

Используем супержадный (ревнивый, possessive) квантификатор: `<tag.*+>`
Откаты не будут производиться вообще:

1. нашли `<tag`. Идем дальше, подбираем под `.*`
2. след. символ пробел. Подходит под `.*` - отлично, пробуем идти дальше и пытаемся и следующие символы проматчить с `.*`: `attr='val'>123 123</tag>` - все, нечего еще добавить, идем дальше
3. подбираем под `>` - а текста-то уже нету. Пофиг, пути назад нет

совпадений нет.

А на счет вертикальной табуляции - так это же просто управляющий символ, такой же как `\n` или `\t`. К регулярным выражениям прямого отношения не имеет. Раньше использовался в принтерах - деталей точных не знаю, но [олдфаги помнят](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3380538/what-is-a-vertical-tab). Таким образом, `\v` просто ищет наличие этого символа в строке.

**UPD.** (комментарий к @knes и @Valeriy Karchov)

Насколько я понимаю, дело в производительности. И жадные, и ленивые квантификаторы хранят обратные ссылки для возможности вернуться назад. Если паттерн сложный, с вложениями, то таких возвратов назад может быть очень много. Если совпадение найдено (или может быть найдено), то все ок, но вот если совпадения нет, то может начаться длительный перебор различных вариантов и в этом случае супержадные квантификаторы быстрее определят, что совпадения нет.

[Здесь](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) приводится хоть и искусственный, но показательный пример: применяем паттерн `(x+x+)+y` к строке вида `xxxxxxxxxxy`. Если `y` в конце есть, то ОК, произойдет только один откат (когда будет искаться совпадение для второго `x+`) и дело сделано. Но вот если `y` в конце нет, то движок будет натужно перебирать все возможные комбинации. Так, у меня на машине этот поиск (Java) в строке из 19-ти `x` занял 2 секунды. С другой стороны, очевидно же, что если какой-либо участок был проматчен с `(x+x+)+`, то `y` там точно нет. Это означает, что мы может установить сверхжадный квантификатор: `(x+x+)++y` - так как мы точно знаем, что откат не приведет к нахождению `y`.

Таким образом, сверхжадные квантификаторы можно использовать в случаях, когда выражение под квантификатором не может заглотнуть символы, которые предполагалось вытащить следующим за квантификатором выражением. В ситуациях с неподходящими входными данными это позволит быстрее определить, что совпадения нет. Так, некоторые движки регулярных выражений даже определяют ситуации типа `[^x]+x` и подставляют туда сверхжадный квантификатор.

Comment: про откаты не понял. =( Что за откаты: иди и иди себе, пока с .* совпадает
Все остальное - я и так понял и по википедии. А вот точный механизм поиска по регулярке, который тут описан - ну никак не понятен

Comment: А в каких случаях рекомендуется использовать супержадный квантификатор?

Comment: все, насчет откатов дошло, наконец-то. Но насчет супержадности - поддерживаю. Получается, в любом случае, если он заканчивается не на .* или .+ или не является точной копией строки, он ничего не найдет. Нафиг такой нужен? Чтобы конец строки гарантированно схавать?

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ