# Регулярные выражения. PHP

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Имеется html. Из него нужно выдернуть текст, в котором могут быть совершенно разные символы, поэтому отталкиваться можно только от тегов. Справа от текста мы имеем только завершающие теги - данный вопрос решен с помощью "`((<\/.*>[\r\n\s]*)+)$`". Сам текст обозначил "`.*`". Слева от текста всегда будет ">". Вот тут возникла проблема - если использовать "`(?<=>)`" - то регуляркой находится первое вхождение и, естественное, выдается кривой результат. Интересует следующее: как можно обозначить "`(?<=>)`" так, что бы оно было последним вхождением. Или, возможно, есть какой-то другой вариант решения задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Либо использовать нежадную проверку
[использование-жадных-greedy-и-супержадных-выражений](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/38045/%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-v-%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-greedy-%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

2) Либо для текста использовать [^>]

Что вам больше подойдет.